# Рисование в C#

Tags: gdi+, winforms, .net

Значит, так. Рисую на форме с помощью `Graphics`. Хочу передать объект `Graphics` в другой класс, в котором будет производиться отрисовка, то есть там саму форму уже видно не будет. Но надо откуда-то взять ширину и высоту "рисовальной" области. Откуда?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Свойство `Graphics.VisibleClipBounds`